# Canvas element not doing anything in unpackaged Chrome app

Tags: html, canvas, google-chrome-app

I am testing out a custom Chrome app, and I decided to use a canvas. I have the usual manifest.json and background.js, but I think the problem is in my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas" style="width:500px;height:500px;border:1px solid black;"></canvas>
    <script>
      var c = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
      c.fillStyle = "red";
      c.fillRect(50,25,50,50);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Whenever I style my canvas, everything shows, but nothing is showing up. However, when I test the same code in the browser window, it shows up. Why is this happening and\or how can I fix it?

Comment: Inline js doesn't work in apps and extensions (the console should show the error).

Comment: Thank you. I moved it to a separate JS file and everything works just fine now.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy